# Include elisp function in org-capture template

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I've tried following some of the other answered questions here regarding this topic but can't seem to get my head around this particular part of the problem.

I have the following function, which returns the value of a key `:PROPERTIES:` pair when a cursor is under an org header:

```
  (defun capture-noter-link ()
    "insert PROPERTY value of pdftools link"
    ;; (interactive)
    (let ((linkStr
           (save-excursion
             (save-window-excursion
               (switch-to-buffer (plist-get org-capture-plist :original-buffer))
               (org-entry-get nil "NOTER_PAGE"))
             )))
      (insert linkStr)))
```

Calling this function interactively while in the source org file gives me the desired result. I then tried to implement this in `org-capture` by using the following template:

```
("ai" "Anki IR"
 entry
 (file+headline org-my-anki-file "Incremental Reading Cards")
          "* %<%H:%M>   %^g\n:PROPERTIES:\n:ANKI_NOTE_TYPE: Cloze\n:ANKI_DECK: MegaDeck\n:END:\n** Text\n%x\n** Extra\n %(capture-noter-link)\n")
```

However the desired link isn't inserted into the capture buffer. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defun insert-property(&optional p)
      "insert PROPERTY value of pdftools link"
      (unless p (setq p "TEST"))
      (message "property passed is: %s" p)
      (let ((pvalue
               (save-window-excursion
                 (message "%s" (org-capture-get :original-buffer))
                 (switch-to-buffer (org-capture-get :original-buffer))
                 (message "retrieved property is: %s" (org-entry-get (point) p))
                 (org-entry-get (point) p)
                 )))
                 pvalue))
```

I don't think you need any `(insert x)` call for a start: the function itself should not insert the string - it should just return it.

I had a fiddle and came up with the above function, just to satisfy my own curiosity. I hope it helps. I used `org-capture-get` and also `(point)` but maybe that's an alternative way.

Just add `%(insert-property "TEST")%` in my capture template.

Test data:-

```
*** scratchpad                                              :tangle no:noexport:
    :PROPERTIES:
    :TEST:     HELLO WORLD
    :END:
```

My template:-

```
("t" "Todo" entry
  (file+headline "refile.org" "Tasks To Refile")
  "* TODO %? %(insert-property "TEST")%
:PROPERTIES:
:DateCreated: %T
:END:
")
```

Comment: "... in my capture template": can you add your capture template to your answer? That will make it self-contained and much more useful.

Comment: So you meant to write "... in your capture template"? If so, please say so.

Comment: I meant to say no such thing. I gave my code and said what needs to be inserted, I had that in MY template to test it. I'm quite happy to delete my solution if you insist on  picking at minutiae. He gave his template and I gave MY code that he can try in HIS template.  FWIW I did add my template to my working code.

Comment: Thank you for including the template. FWIW, I'm not trying to pick at minutiae: I'm trying to make the answer as useful as possible to the OP and anybody else who might have the same (or similar) question. I thought the basics of the answer were correct, so it was worth to improve it as much as possible.

Comment: Using the above example I get the desired PROPERTY echoed in the minibuffer when testing it interactively. I then remove (interactive) and test with your minimal scratchpad and template example, but the capture buffer returns this: `** TODO  %(insert-property` , with the last paren cut off like that.

Comment: Removing the quoted string `"TEST"` from the capture, and using `%(insert-property)` instead produces the desired result when tested with my target `NOTER_PAGE` property. I have to use `(unless p (setq p "NOTER_PAGE"))` in the func however.